# Layout weight is not fit, it change every input

Tags: android, android-layout, styles, android-linearlayout

I have a spinner, an edittext and a button in a horizontal linearlayout. When I have enter something into edittext, it increase every character and others decrease. There is an eanough blank area input but it does not change, every time it increase how long character I input.
How can I fix it?

layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/ly"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        style="@style/submitspinner"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:entries="@array/a_code"
        android:prompt="@string/p_code" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        style="@style/submitstyle"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="@style/submitstyle"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="@string/btn_submit" />
</LinearLayout>
```

style

```
<style name="submitstyle">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">10sp</item> 
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/pt</item> 
</style>
<style name="submitspinner" parent="@android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">10sp</item> 
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/pt</item> 
</style>
```

Comment: use `android:layout_width=match_parent` for the elements that are inside the linear layout

Comment: Edittext is not shown...
Spinner and button fill the whole line...

Comment: you have used `android:layout_width=match_parent` and the weights you have displayed there and the edittext is not shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed style as below and it worked well...
submitstyle and submitspinner style

from

```
<item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
```

to

```
<item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
```

I found good tuts for this but I have closed the tab, I cannot share it...

Answer (score 0):

//change you style from

```
<item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
```

//to

```
<item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
```